# Создание двумерного массива в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как обозначить двумерный массив в JS одной строкой?
Можно, конечно, написать `A = new Array`, а затем циклом пройтись `A[i] = new Array`, но можно без циклов как-то обойтись, а задать одной строкой?

Comment: если количество строк неизвестно - то нельзя. Чем не устраивают циклы?

Comment: @Grundy, можно всё :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а ну-ка давай :)

Comment: @Grundy, так я же уже))

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я не видел ответа :-) в любом случае - те же циклы :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если я понял, то вот так

```
var arr = [[],[]]
```

Comment: Можно с каретками для красоты - [['^'],['^']];

Comment: а что делают каретки?

Comment: @cronfy, ничего, бака  \\['^']/

Answer (score 2):

Не сказал бы, что хорошее решение, но в принципе к вопросу подходит :)

```
var n = 10
var a = Array(n).fill().map(() => [])
```